# How to Fetch Cookie and Set Cookie Short-code With Ajax

Tags: php, wordpress, cookies

TLDR: Form Pluggin has a bug I cant do this the sane way.

My JS file Creates the Cookie It gets passed to the Php Function that creates a Shortcut that holds that Value, This is to set the Value of a Form Field.

The cookie Updates when the Dropwdown Selection Changes.
I need to find a way to Update this Shortcodes Value(The cookie) Before the Form Submits or a Reload occurs
I am almost dead sure this would occur with Ajax My last bit of code will be my very poor attempt at Using Ajax.
Small Note I cant seem to create the Shortcode if its not in my Functions.php this complicates things a bit

How can I more or less achieve the aforementioned

Code:

```js
var strUser = e.value; 
var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
document.cookie = "visaSelect = " + strUser;
createCookie("visaSelect", strUser, "1");

function createCookie(name, value, days) {
    var expires;
        if (days) {
            var date = new Date();
            date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
            expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
        }else {
                expires = "";
        }
           document.cookie = escape(name) + "=" + escape(value) + expires + ";";
}
```

```php
add_action('frm_submit_button_action', 'your_function_name');
 function your_function_name($form){
   if($form->id == 3){ 
     echo frm_referrer_cookie();
   }
}

add_shortcode( 'frm_referrer_cookie', 'frm_referrer_cookie' );
add_action('frm_referrer_cookie', 'frm_referrer_cookie_action'); // Not even sure if u can do this
function frm_referrer_cookie() {
    
        $value = $_COOKIE["visaSelect"];

    return $value;
}
```

My Very bad Attempt at using Ajax

```
function createCookie(name, value, days) {
    var expires;
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
        expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
    }else {
        expires = "";
     }
    document.cookie = escape(name) + "=" + escape(value) + expires + ";";
    var Cookie = function(callback) {
        $.ajax({
        url: "functions.php"
        }).done(callback);
        }
        alert(Cookie);          
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent the form from submitting, update the cookie and then submit. Here's an example with jQuery...

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('form').on('submit', function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); // Stops form from submitting
        // Get the required form input and call JS function to update cookie value
        $(this).submit(); // Then submit
    });
});
```